# solving Work distribution related problem easily

Tags: linear-algebra

If Mar, Rox, & Haz writes 9, 4 & 10 hours respectively, then 7 stories are made. If Mar writes 3 hours, Rox writes 8 hours, then 5 stories are made. If Rox writes 6 hours, Haz writes 5 hours, then 4 stories are made. How long does it take each writer to make 1 story writing alone?

is there any general rule to solve this question? How will I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\frac{1}{m}$ the number of stories that Mar writes in 1 hour. $\frac{1}{r}$ and $\frac{1}{h}$ have similar meanings.

Mar writes in 9 hours $\frac{9}{m}$ stories. Rox writes in 4 hours $\frac{4}{r}$ stories. Haz writes in 10 hours $\frac{10}{h}$ stories. Together they write in $9,4$ and $10$ hours 7 stories respectively. Therefore the equation is

$$\frac{9}{m}+\frac{4}{r}+\frac{10}{h}= 7$$

The other two equations have to be set up similarly. Then you have three variables and three equations. This  equation system has a unique solution.